# java: given a string, pick numbers in it, sort them in ascending order, and then print the result

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

As title suggests. For example, if the input is `9103ndhai*25ma@#$`, the program should output `012359`.
This is my attempt:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    Scanner cin = new Scanner (System.in);
    String myString = "";
    while (cin.hasNext()) {
        int tempInt = cin.nextInt();
        myString = myString + tempInt;
    }

    Scanner intScan = new Scanner (myString);
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList();
    while (intScan.hasNext()) {
        int tempInt2 = intScan.nextInt();
        intList.add(tempInt2);
    }

    Collections.sort (intList);
    for (int i=0; i<intList.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(intList.get(i));
    }
}
```

This is gives wrong results. I am trying to use Scanner particularly, but I think I have some misunderstandings of the class (gonna look closer to api). Any suggestions?

Comment: General flow:  read in string, for each char in string, if digit, figure out numeric value, add to list.  at end, sort list

Comment: Tip: use hasNextInt()

Comment: Based on your example output, it looks like you want to extract digits, not numbers, correct?

Comment: yeah digit is what i want not numbers...sry for confusions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I elaborate your code and try to use it:

```
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList();
    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the sequence");//9103ndhai*25ma@#$
    String myString = "";
        String tempInt = cin.next();
        for(int i = 0; i< tempInt.length(); i++){
            String s = ""+tempInt.charAt(i);
        if(s.matches("[0-9]"))
            intList.add(Integer.parseInt(""+tempInt.charAt(i)));
        }


    Collections.sort (intList);
    for (int i=0; i<intList.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(intList.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = scanner.next();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d"); //Matches single digits (from 0-9) - prepend -? to the regex to react to "negative" digits
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (m.find()) {
        integers.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
    }
    Collections.sort(integers);

    integers.forEach(System.out::print);
}
```